# Using ToString method at first in Expression Tree

Tags: c#, expression-trees

I'm new to expression Tree and I need to convert the below lambda to Expression Tree

```
Data.Where(s => s.Property.ToString().StartsWith("My Search Data"));
```

However I have done upto

```
Data.Where(s => s.Property.StartsWith("My Search Data");
```

Now I Need to use the ToString Method before Using StartsWith.

Below is my sample code.

```
ParameterExpression e = Expression.Parameter(typeof(T), "e");
PropertyInfo propertyInfo = typeof(T).GetProperty(field);
MemberExpression m = Expression.MakeMemberAccess(e, propertyInfo);
ConstantExpression c = Expression.Constant(data, typeof(string));
MethodInfo mi = typeof(string).GetMethod("StartsWith", new Type[] { typeof(string) });
Expression call = Expression.Call(m, mi, c);
Expression<Func<T, bool>> lambda = Expression.Lambda<Func<T, bool>>(call, e);
query = query.Where(lambda);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The ideea is that you have to get "ToString" method from System.Object. Because it is a virtual method, the Runtime can dispatch the call on your real object.

Note: IData is your whatever data that has a property named "Property".

```
ParameterExpression e = Expression.Parameter(typeof(IData), "e");
PropertyInfo propertyInfo = typeof(IData).GetProperty("Property");
MemberExpression m = Expression.MakeMemberAccess(e, propertyInfo);

var toString = typeof (Object).GetMethod("ToString");

ConstantExpression c = Expression.Constant(data, typeof(string));
MethodInfo mi = typeof(string).GetMethod("StartsWith", new Type[] { typeof(string) });

var toStringValue = Expression.Call(m, toString);

Expression call = Expression.Call(toStringValue, mi, c);

Expression<Func<IData, bool>> lambda = Expression.Lambda<Func<IData, bool>>(call, e);
```

Comment: Worked Perfectly. Really a great thanks from bottom of my heart. Can you please suggest me some good book for Expression Tree

Comment: In my opinion you have to learn first reflection and the stuff behind .NET. For that, I would recommend "CLR via C#" by Jeffrey Richter. Next, you could try to start playing with them (I learned them until mastering them just by playing with Expression API's at home). As an exercise, try to get whatever function (no matter what, but start with simple ones) and try to translate it into expression trees (or at least a part of it). Do this translation until you master them.

Comment: Or look at decompiled code, to see how the compiler translates your lambdas to the expression API

Comment: @RohitRohela I would recommend you use [this debugging visualizer](https://github.com/zspitz/ExpressionToString#visual-studio-debugger-visualizer-for-expression-trees). (Disclaimer: I am the author of the visualizer.)

Answer (score 6):

Consider using the overloads that allow you to access members by name instead.  It will make this significantly easier to do.

```
// Data.Where(s => s.Property.ToString().StartsWith("My Search Data"));
var property = "Property";
var filter = "My Search Data";
var param = Expression.Parameter(typeof(T));
var body = Expression.Call(
    Expression.Call(
        Expression.Property(param, property),
        "ToString",
        null
    ),
    "StartsWith",
    null,
    Expression.Constant(filter)
);
var lambda = Expression.Lambda<Func<T, bool>>(body, param);
```

Comment: It worked. Although the first answer has solved my problem but you have provided one more way of the solution. Thanks :)